# What's the correct way to version pyproject.toml

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning, pyproject.toml

According to this article https://py-pkgs.org/07-releasing-versioning.html, versions in `pyproject.toml` follow the semantic versioning standarts.
So my file looks like :

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my_project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "..."
...
```

Wanting to build a pre-release, I wrote `0.1.0-1` as version number.
That should be allowed according to https://semver.org/ 
But my build is rejected and I have to set `0.1.0.1`, which doesn't fit standarts.

Is it a misconfiguration of my Jenkins project or another third party tool, or `0.1.0.1` is indeed the intended way to write versions

Comment: Poorly encoded error that I don't have the courage to send in main post : 
`[1mInvalid version: '0.2.0-2b'[0m
 
at [32m/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/core/version/version.py[0m:[1m61[0m in [36m__init__[0m
    [0m[35;1mdef [0m[39m__init__[0m[39;2m([0m[39;1mself[0m[39;2m, [0m[39mversion[0m[39;2m):  [0m[39;2;3m# type: (str) -> None[0m
;2;3m        # Validate the version and parse it into pieces[0m
        match [0m[39;2m= [0m[39mVERSION_PATTERN[0m[39;2m.[0m[39mmatch[0m[39;2m([0m[39mversion[0m[39;2m)[0m`

Comment: refer to this [article](https://blog.inedo.com/python-best-practices-for-versioning-python-packages-in-the-enterprise), section **Best Practice: Build Prerelease Packages**